# Exchange 2013 DAG Cluster Unable to add second sever

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, windows-server-2012-r2, exchange-2013, failovercluster, dag

I have two servers (EXCH1 and EXCH2) running Exchange Server 2013 Standard, and a third file server that is a DAG Witness.

The first server is a Windows Server 2012 R2 Standard machine and the second server is a Windows Server 2008 R2 Enterprise machine (on an HP Proliant DL360 G4). Both servers have Client Access and Mailbox Roles on them.

I am able to successfully add only one of the two servers as a member server. When I try to add the second server, (regardless of which one ends up being the second server) it fails. It stalls after being at "Adding Server (EXCH1 or EXCH2) to the cluster for an extended amount of time".. Then an error message displays...

> error
>
> A server-side database availability group administrative operation
>   failed. Error The operation failed. CreateCluster errors may result
>   from incorrectly configured static addresses. Error: The operation
>   failed. CreateCluster errors may result from incorrectly configured
>   static addresses. Error: An error occurred while attempting a cluster
>   operation. Error: Cluster API '"AddClusterNode() (MaxPercentage=100)
>   failed with 0x5b4. Error: This operation returned because the timeout
>   period expired"' failed.. [Server: (SERVER FQDN)

I have taken these additional steps also:

1. Ensured that each server is updated appropriately (Windows Update)
2. Admin account with proper credentials used.
3. IP and NIC settings on each server OK.
4. DNS listings of each host also OK.
5. Exchange Server 2013 running as normal on each server.
6. Cluster Manager service(s) started and running on each server.
7. All Windows Firewall ports added to list, Windows Firewall has even been completely disabled to troubleshoot.

It seems like the two servers don't like talking to each other (regardless of which direction the communication is)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Mixed OS version clusters are not supported. Get all of your servers on the same version.

See: [Planning for high availability and site resilience](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd638104(v=exchg.160).aspx#SoftReq) (Microsoft Technet)

> Each member of a DAG must be running the same operating system.

Comment: ...and here I was the whole time trying to figure this whole things out. haha. I deployed a VM with Server 2012 R2 and wit works fine in the DAG. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you face same problem in Exchange 2019 server:

```
Clear-ClusterNode -Name XXXXXX (Problematic Server) -Force (PowerShall)
```

Restart the server

```
Add-DatabaseAvailabilityGroupServer -Identity "DAG Name" -MailboxServer XXXXXX(Problematic Server)
```

Server should be added and validate the DAG members and FileShare.

Answer (score -1):

First of all we have to tackle the access denied part of it and it can be cleared by checking and assigning the required permissions.
Error is also showing that static IP has miss-configured so ensure that it is assigned perfectly as per the necessity
There might not be a DAG1 account created by whereas DAG account could be there which an Exchange Console formulate without any problems/error. So ensure that DAG1 account has created in the place.
Read more here : http://www.tips.omsaitech.co.in/a-server-side-database-availability-group-administrative-operation-failed-error-the-computer-account-dag1-could-not-be-validated-access-was-denied-check-that-the-current-user-nt-authoritysy/